# Please recommend simple and light virtualization technology for linux

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines

I have used VmWare for a long time but now support for Linux is near broken. I need new technology.

Why I refuse vmware: after some update hardware and firmware I found out my vmware-server 1.0.6 broken. I try update it up to 1.0.9, but found out then vmware-server-console have fatal bug which does not have fixes and require to recompile X. I try update again up to 2.0.1 but found out then vmware at now does not have usable server console at all. firefox plugin is not usable. and also I find out then at now vmware not interested in Linux customers at all. From that time I try to find alternatives

Comment: Perhaps you couple explain the faults with VMware and how it works with Linux.

Comment: This is obviously not meant to be an answerable question.

Comment: If you do not tell us about your problems with VMWare, it's unlikely we can suggest something that works better for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).

Comment: +1 , Virtualbox is going to feel a lot like what he's used to.

Comment: *TNANKS*

VirtualBox is acceptable for me

Answer (score 3):

Good discussion about a few of them here: [Which virtualization platforms should I choose, Xen or OpenVZ?](https://serverfault.com/questions/12110/which-virtualization-platforms-should-i-choose-xen-or-openvz), or there's also [KVM](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm)

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of which technology you end up going with, I suggest you use [libvirt](http://libvirt.org/) to manage it. libvirt supports LXC and OpenVZ containers, as well as KVM, Xen and VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

For desktop use the best I can recommend is VirtualBox from Sun.
For servers, Vmware ESX will do well for you.

Comment: vmware-server-console up to 1.0.9 written by developer with bug in genome.

if ESX was written same developers - I do not want have relation with vmware at all

Answer (score 1):

I have been using VirtualBox since right before Sun bought them and it has not steered me wrong. I am using it on my Mac and all of my Linux boxes. When my laptop was Ubuntu, I used vbox to run WinXP for my standard work stuff. It started bogging down because I only had 1.5GB of RAM in the laptop. My new laptop will hopefully get 4GB so that I can go back to linux and comfortable run WinXP in vbox.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

There are **different** levels of [virtualisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine#Operating_system-level_virtualization). The lightest weight would be OS-level virtualisation. OS-level virtualisation for Linux is [OpenVZ](http://wiki.openvz.org/Main_Page)/[VServer](http://linux-vserver.org/Welcome_to_Linux-VServer.org). These are similar to BSD-Jails/Solaris-Zones. The only catch is that they **only** run Linux virtual machines and no other OS.

Comment: a jail is not a proper virtualization, it is just a way to isolate an environment. In a virtual guest I expect to run different OS, different libs, different bit arch, have __virtual hardware__, and so on. A jail-like approach is the lighter, but is not true virtualization.

Comment: Untrue. There are different levels of virtualisation. What you said is just one type of it - paravirtualisation. OS-Level virtualisation is another kind.

Answer (score 0):

VMware has been from the beginning of virtualization. Their tools are the best in my oppinion

http://www.vmware.com/download/ws/
(you can download a trial and test it)

Comment: Not trying to be snarky here, but did you read that he wasn't happy with VMWare?

Comment: i saw after the first post :(

Comment: vmware-server-console up to 1.0.9 written by developer with bug in genome. if other code was written same developers - I do not want have relation with vmware at all.